# How to interpret the statement $\forall z. \exists u \forall x. (\exists y. x \in y$ AND $y \in z)$ IFF $x \in u.$?

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, axioms

This is one of the ZFC Axioms. It says:

```
Union: The union, u, of a collection, z, of sets is also a set.
```

I interpret the statement in this way: For all z, there exists u for which for all x, there exists y such that x belongs to y AND y belongs to z, if and only if x belongs to u.

So this statement means if x is in both y and z, then it will be in u too. Since y is a set, making a union of all y's will have all the non repeating elements from those y's in u. Thus, u is a set.

I am not sure if my interpretation is correct or there is more to the statement. I don't know how to make a logical statement after reading the union axiom.

Comment: What do the dots mean after some of the variables in the title?

Comment: Also, the title has IFF and your "interpretation" doesn't.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I found in the internet, dots mean "such that". I understand what IFF means, that's why I did not emphasize it in the question. But I am changing it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Union axiom](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/ZF.html) :

> $∀z ∃u ∀x [x ∈ u ↔ ∃y(x ∈ y \text { and } y \in z)]$

asserts that for any given set $z$ there is a set $u$  which has as members all of the members of all of the members of $z$.

This does not mean : "if $x$ is in both $y$ and $z$, then it will be in $u$ too."

The set $u$ is the set of the **elements of the elements** of $z$; thus : "if $x$ is in $y$ which is in $z$, then it will be in $u$."

Comment: In my head it was something like this, but after reading this, it's more clear now. I have one confusion: if $x$ is in $y$, which is in $z$, then it will be in $u$. Now, how does this make sure $x$ is not repeated in $u$, meaning $u$ is a set? For example, from Fareed Abi Farraj's answer, if Z={{1,2},{2,3,4},{5,6}} then how does this logical statement make sure it is not $U =$ {$1,2,2,3,4,5,6$}?

Comment: @alu - because sets are [Extensional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality) i.e. an "object" can occur in a set without multiplicity. In other words : $\{ 2,2 \} = \{ 2 \}$

Comment: This wikipedia article is very interesting and clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is incorrect in two ways:

When you say "$x$ is in both $y$ and $z$, you don't realize that $y$ and $z$ lie at different layers of sets: $z$ is a collection of sets, and $y$ is one of them.

Secondly, the statement is an equivalence, and your "interpretation" goes one way only.

The correct interpretation is "there is a set $u$ such that for any object $x$, $x$ lies in $u$ if and only if $x$ lies in at least one set $y$ from the collection $z$".

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you an example and apply the axiom on it, and I hope this'll help.

$Z= \{\{1,2\}, \{2,3,4\}, \{5,6\}\}$ (a collection of sets)

$U=\{1,2\}\cup \{2,3,4\}\cup \{5,6\}=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ (the union of the collection of sets, that is also a set)

Now we can say $\{1,2\} \in Z$, and we can say $2\in U$ or $3\in U$ ... and note that we don't say  $2\in Z$ (because somehow $2$ is an element, so it can belong to a set of elements, but $Z$ is a set of sets, and that is why we can say that $\{1,2\} \in Z$)